# gcm is not working for real device

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Android Push Notifications using Google Cloud Messaging (GCM), PHP and MySQL for real mobile wireless is any one know to config means in emulator the device id can easily feed to the database but in real device how can feed the  device id it cant access the database how can enter the device id to database ?

Comment: Please show all relevant code, also are you making sure each device real or emulator have a google account setup on the device as this is required for the gcm to work correctly and to get a device id.

Comment: People usually have a problem with emulator not real device. Remember that device have to have a valid Google account to make GCM work.

Answer (score 0):

Simply follow the instructions on [this page](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html):

specifically:

```
/**
 * Main UI for the demo app.
 */
public class DemoActivity extends Activity {

    public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "message";
    public static final String PROPERTY_REG_ID = "registration_id";
    private static final String PROPERTY_APP_VERSION = "appVersion";
    private static final String PROPERTY_ON_SERVER_EXPIRATION_TIME =
            "onServerExpirationTimeMs";
    /**
     * Default lifespan (7 days) of a reservation until it is considered expired.
     */
    public static final long REGISTRATION_EXPIRY_TIME_MS = 1000 * 3600 * 24 * 7;

    /**
     * Substitute you own sender ID here.
     */
    String SENDER_ID = "Your-Sender-ID";

    /**
     * Tag used on log messages.
     */
    static final String TAG = "GCMDemo";

    TextView mDisplay;
    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm;
    AtomicInteger msgId = new AtomicInteger();
    SharedPreferences prefs;
    Context context;

    String regid;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display);

        context = getApplicationContext();
        regid = getRegistrationId(context);

        if (regid.length() == 0) {
            registerBackground();
        }
        gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
    }
...
}
```